# React Native Reanimated: Reading from `_value` directly is only possible on the UI runtime

Tags: react-native, reanimated, react-native-modal

Я в своем проекте хочу использовать `React Native Reanimated`, что бы текст поднимался, когда на поле делается фокус. Пример кода:

```
const top = useSharedValue(0);
const fontSize = useSharedValue(16);

const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      top: top.value,
      fontSize: fontSize.value,
    };
  });

<Text style={[css.label, animatedStyle]}>{t(label)}</Text>
```

Сама форма размещена в модалке (react-native-modal). Но я получаю ошибку

```
Reading from `_value` directly is only possible on the UI runtime
```

На другом проекте я делаю точно так же и там работает. Отличие - в том проекте форма не в модалке.

Может кто сталкивался и знает как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Решение здесь очень простое.

Вместо импортирования компонента `Animated` из `react-native`, как вы делали, видимо, до этого:

```js
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
```

нужно импортировать этот компонент непосредственно из `react-native-reanimated`:

```js
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle } from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот моё решение:

```
<Animated.View style={[animatedStyle]}>
  //your view
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: If the only language you know is English, please, write them on [Stack Overflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead of Russian Stack Overflow.